# How to use HGT files in MapInfo

Tags: dem, mapinfo

I have a SRTM-3 file and I want to use it to make a DEM of the related world region. I'm using MapInfo **Professionale V8** and I'm fairly new to that software,

so if there is any tutorial that shows how to use the SRTM file to get a DEM in order to make an elevation map it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To load SRTM data in MapInfo and create a DEM from it, you need two things: (1) [Vertical Mapper](http://www.pitneybowes.com/uk/location-intelligence/geographic-information-system/mapinfo-vertical-mapper.html) (an extension to MapInfo) (2) SRTM of ASCII format.

The Vertical Mapper has a tool to import external formats, but it has limited number of formats that can be imported into MapInfo, but luckily ASCII format is one of them. If the SRTM that you have is not in ASCII format, you need to download it again. You can download SRTM of ASCII format from [cgiar.org](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp) and there is an option to download the data in ArcInfo ASCII which Vertical Mapper can read and import. You can refer to [Vertical Mapper PDF manual](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/vertical_mapper/english/3_7/VerticalMapperUserGuide.pdf) on how to import ASCII format and convert it into MapInfo format.